# Rails emoji picker won't load for Simple_Form textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using a gem called **rails_emoji_picker** to easily implement an emoji solution for my project. The gem is not loading the emoji picker inside of the textarea, even though I followed the instructions that were given. I see no errors in my javascript debugging console. How can I make the emoji picker display inside of the textarea? I'm currently using **rails 5**. https://github.com/ID25/rails_emoji_picker

post _form.html.erb

```
    <div class=container">
<%= simple_form(@post, multipart: true, remote: true) do |f| %>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
        <p class="emoji-picker-container">
        <%= f.input :body_text, class: 'form-control', label: false, id: 'text-area-reset', placeholder: 'write something', data: {emojiable: true} %>
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6>
        <%= f.button :submit, 'Post it', class: 'btn btn-outline-success' %>
        </div>
        </div>
<% end %>
        </div>
```

Comment: I think the problem is you're generating a text field instead of a textarea. Try `f.input :body_text, as: :text, ... ` See the documentation for Simple Form here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Comment: I changed it to text, but the panel does not show. If possible, can you test the gem with simple_form and report back to this thread with a complete solution?